# Batch: Script already gets names of folders and subfolders - how do I get filenames without extension?

Tags: batch-file, directory, filenames, output, subdirectory

This script gets the folder-names and its sub-folder-names and sve them into a HTML-file. I also need the filenames of all files which are in the subfolders (without the extension). I pimped the script with some HTML.

**list.cmd**

```
@echo off
chcp 1252
del D:\list.html
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /ad /b D:\packing') do (
echo ^<center^>^<b^>^<font size="4" color="#ffffff" face="Lucida Sans Unicode, Lucida Grande" style="background-color:#4682b4;"^>^&nbsp; >> D:\list.html
echo %%G ^&nbsp; >> D:\list.html
echo ^</b^>^<a href="#" style="color:#4682b4; text-decoration:none;"^> >> D:\list.html
echo ^</a^>^</font^>^<br^>^</center^> >> D:\list.html
echo ^<center^>^<font size="2" color="#000000" face="Verdana"^> >> D:\list.html
call D:\packing\list2.cmd "%%G"
echo ^</font^>^</center^>^<br^>^<br^> >> D:\list.html
)
```

**list2.cmd**

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%H in ('dir /ad /b D:\packing\%1') do echo %%H ^<br^> >> D:\list.html
echo. >> D:\list.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the file name without the extension for every file in all subfolders using

```
for /r C:\dirname %%a in (*) do echo %%~na
```

That will `echo` them all. Just modify and use it in your script where you need it.

Comment: +1 And to see all of the modifiers for `for` loop variables type `for /?` into the command line. Or http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490909.aspx

Comment: Thanks. I am using this script many times in different folders and I always put in in the folder where all the subfolders are from which I want the filenames. So, how can I change "C:\dirname" to "current directory"?

Comment: No worries. You can just take out the `C:\dirname` bit and leave it as `for /r %%a ...` to use the current directory.